# Code::Blocks и консоль

Tags: c, ide, отладка, gdb, codeblocks

...за баранку этого пылесоса! Есть проект на C, консоль. В качестве терминала стоит предустановка для XFCE:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любая попытка начать отладку выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Нет" - и можно отлаживаться. Что ему надо, о чём это вообще, и как лечить?

P.S. NetBeans не предлагать: как раз сейчас и экспериментирую любопытства ради, раз в день полностью менять IDE на одном и том же проекте (C).

Comment: warning связан со спецификой запуска gdb. наиболее полно, как мне кажется, проблема исследована [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7439161/4827341). по-моему, наиболее простое решение проблемы: отметить галочку "don't annoy me again" в окне диалога, приведённом на скриншоте.

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю. Прежде чем жать на галочку хочется понять на что это может повлиять. Например, по ссылке пишут, что после этого "debugging functionality is not available", а тут вроде как что-то работает...